# Xamarin BLE scanning only sometimes

Tags: xamarin, bluetooth

I created simple Xamarin.Forms Bluetooth low energy scanning application. As I will use Bluetooth only on Android, I implemented scanning in MainActivity.cs of Android project:

```
namespace BlankAppXamlXamarinForms.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "BlankAppXamlXamarinForms", Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@style/MainTheme", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        private BluetoothManager _manager;
        App app;

        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            app = new App();

            var appContext = Application.Context;
            _manager = (BluetoothManager)appContext.GetSystemService(BluetoothService);
            _manager.Adapter.BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan(new MyScanCallback(app));

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
    }

    public class MyScanCallback : ScanCallback
    {
        App _app;
        public MyScanCallback(App app) {
            _app = app;
        }

        public override void OnScanResult(ScanCallbackType callbackType, ScanResult result)
        {
            _app.newDevice(result.Device.Name + " - " + result.Device.Address);
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that OnScanResult receives advertising packets only a moment after the application is started and when I switch the display of my phone off and then turn it on again. Meanwhile the application receives almost no advertising packets. How to receive advertising packets all the time my application is active?

Comment: Look at sticky services

Comment: I don't need a service running in background. I just want to receive advertising packets all the time application is visible on the display.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating two instances of `App`. Instead of `LoadApplication(new App());` you should be passing in your field `app`, i.e. `LoadApplication(app);`

Also, instead of starting the scan in `OnCreate`, you might want to start the scan in `OnResume` and stop the scan in `OnPause` e.g.:

```
public class MainActivity : FormsAppCompatActivity
{
    BluetoothManager bleManager;
    App app;
    ScanCallback scanCallback;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
        ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        Forms.Init(this, bundle);

        app = new App();
        bleManager = (BluetoothManager)Application.Context.GetSystemService(BluetoothService);
        scanCallback = new MyScanCallback(app);

        LoadApplication(new App());
    }

    protected override void OnResume()
    {
        base.OnResume();
        bleManager.Adapter.BluetoothLeScanner.StartScan(scanCallback);
    }

    protected override void OnPause()
    {
        base.OnPause();
        bleManager.Adapter.BluetoothLeScanner.StopScan(scanCallback);
    }
}
```